# Can't Edit NSWindow's Toolbar - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, border, nswindow

So I'm using the method:

```
[someWindow setContentBorderThickness:24.0 forEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
```

But I can't seem to get the toolbar to increase in height. It simply stays the same as in default. Can anyone shed some light here?

Answer (score 2):

An `NSToolbar` is automatically resized to accommodate the height of the tallest `NSToolbarItem`. The standard (large) toolbar items are all 32 px tall, so the toolbar has no need to make itself larger. If you do something like add a custom view toolbar item, then it will be resized to accommodate that item, as shown in the image below:

[image]

(To accomplish the result shown above, I clicked on the toolbar twice in IB to bring down the Allowed Toolbar Items sheet, then dragged an `NSView` custom view from the library palette onto that sheet).

P.S. I'd recommend using this capability with discretion.

Comment: Thank you NSGod! (Lol, nice name). I'll give it a go and let you know of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify an arbitrary height for `NSToolbar`. You can, however, specify a size mode. A toolbar with 24x24-pixel icons has a small size mode:

```
[toolbar setSizeMode: NSToolbarSizeModeSmall];
```

which is equivalent to Size: Small in Interface Builder’s Attributes Inspector.

Comment: So I'm doing [[window toolbar] setSizeMod: NSToolbarSizeModeSmall]; and it stays the same in size. Why isn't it changing? I simply want to enlarge the size of the toolbar.

Comment: @Kevin Use `NSToolbarSizeModeRegular` instead. There are only two sizes: regular or small.

Comment: ... otherwise, you'll have to get rid of the toolbar and just use -setContentBorderThickness: to define an area you use as your own custom toolbar. Official toolbars (NSToolbar) have only two sizes as Bavarious said. If you want custom stuff, you'll have to do it all yourself (no NSToolbar). That's what -setContentBorderThickness: for the top edge is like.

Comment: Aww man, I don't want to create a whole new toolbar just to increase height. By the way, Bavarious the NSToolBarSizeModeRegular doesn't give in either.